# How to find out the rows with a repeating element in a particular column and add all the corresponding elements of other columns?

Tags: matlab, simulation, rows, repeat

I have a huge simulation data which needs to be post processed in MATLAB.
Say my matrix is A and its columns are named as variables `ID`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `s1`, `s2` and `s3`. Actually my requirement is I want to find out rows with repeated `X` (here I mean that I am having many points for one value of x-coordinate) and add all the corresponding elements of columns `s1` and `s2`, and divide each by no. of occurrences of `X`. Finally I want `s1`, `s2` and `s3` averaged over their frequency of occurrences.

It may be very trivial question, but, as a beginner I searched & tried a lot in this web, but cud not advance much. I know we can find out the repeated rows and their frequency by using commands like mode or unique etc. but iam not able to add the corresponding column elements and do averaging.

Finally when I want to plot say `X` vs. `s1`, I should have only one value of `s1` for each value of `x1`. (i.e. `s1` needs to be averaged over all repeating `X`)

Do we have any direct matlab command for this or we need to use some loop?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function in matlab named `grpstats` that solves your very problem.
It computes groupwise summary statistics, for data in a matrix or dataset array.

Example:

```
data = [1,2,3,4];
group = [1,1,1,3];
[name,mean] =  grpstats(data, group,{'gname','mean'})
```

would output:

```
name = 

'1'
'3'


mean =

 2
 4
```

You may type `help grpstats` in Matlab for more information.

Comment: Sir,Actually i wan to group (sum and average) only columns s1 s2 and s3, not the first column (as its not required for my plot)...will u PLEASE elaborate...Thanx

Comment: @Subbu You can reference a part of the matrix like `foo(:,2:4)`. In your case, I think you need something like `[name,mean] = grpstats(A(:,2:4),A(:,1),{'gname','mean'})` to group only column 2-4 based on the value in column 1.